# How to use two diferent routing modules with angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I want to add two routing modules in my angular project but I can't, I want to do something like this:

- If you go to /contact it goes to ContactComponent
- If I go to /admin/dashboard it goes to the AdminComponent that there is a sidebar and then in the right part of the website goes to the DashboardComponent
- If I go to /admin/surveys it does the same that the 2nd case, it goes to Admin Component with the sidebar and then it opens SurveysComponent

Now I can create a normal routing module that works with normal urls like the contact page, but I don't know how to **add another routing module** for the admin pages like /admin/surveys or /admin/dashboard. Another option is add two routing outlets but one of them is in a diferent component and it is in into the first routing outlet. I mean something like this:

```
<router-outlet name="r1">
    ContactComponent or
    AdminComponent
        <router-outlet name="r2">
            DashboardComponent or
            SurveysComponent
        </router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

My code:

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'admin', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
    { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**admin.component.html**

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <!--Here is the menu-->
</div>
<div class="content">
    <router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**admin-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' },
    { path: 'surveys', component: SurveysComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: The code that you showed seems to be just right. I worked in an app with composite routes and it's just like that. What's going wrong?

Comment: Now only runs the ContactComponent and the AdminComponent with the sidebar but the subpages like Dashboard or Surveys doesn't load in the AdminComponent

Answer (score 0):

Angular does not know that the admin routes are children for the admin component. You can completely lazy load the admin module (see https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#add-another-feature-module) or define the children in the `app-routing.module.ts`

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'admin', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
    { 
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        children: [{ 
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'dashboard',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        }, {
            path: 'dashboard',
            component: DashboardComponent,
            outlet: 'sidebar'
        }, {
            path: 'surveys',
            component: SurveysComponent,
            outlet: 'sidebar'
        }]
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Your code is not working for me because I think it couldn' find the router-outler "sidebar" because is in another component. I don't know exactly the problem but is not working.

Comment: your outlet needs to be in in the template of the `AdminComponent`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't use child routes. If `surveys` is a child route for `Admin`, then, you need to move the `{ path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },` to the `admin-routing.module.ts` and do the following:

```
{
    path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, children:
      [
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' },
{ path: 'surveys', component: SurveysComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' },

      ]
  }
```

But you have to consider the sequence of the importation of router modules in the `app.module.ts`. Let me explain more.
In the `app-routing.module.ts`: you have these routes

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'admin', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
```

In the `admin-routing.module.ts`: you have these routes

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
```

Of course, you import the `admin-routing.module.ts` in the `admin.module.ts`, but the sequence of importing `AdminModule` and `AppRoutingModule` in the `app.module.ts` is very important. WHY?

For example, in the import section `app.module.ts`, if you write `AdminModule, AppRoutingModule`, then the paths `""` and `"**"` of the admin-routing.module.ts will always be matched and any unmatched routing will be directed to the dashboard. If you do the reverse imporatation sequence like that `AppRoutingModule, AdminModule`, then the "" and "**" will be directed to the admin route.
So, be careful about the sequence of importation of Routing Modules